# Maven repository for Lucene 4.0-SNAPSHOT (or 5.0-SNAPSHOT)

Tags: maven, solr, lucene

I cannot find a maven repository for Lucene 4.0. I don't want to use [my own](https://github.com/karussell/mvnrepo) as it does not get update automatically etc.

Do you have a hint? I already tried the following repos without success (4.0 is not available there):

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/

Comment: I thought lucene core 3.5 was latest.. [are you sure?](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html#27+November+2011+-+Lucene+Core+3.5.0)

Comment: @Nishant. OP wants a SNAPSHOT of 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here:

https://builds.apache.org//job/Lucene-Solr-Maven-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/maven_artifacts/

From the developers documentation page: http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/developer-resources.html

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I could have missed that ... can I somehow refer to a specific version? I don't want to move to a more recent version automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following maven configuration for lucene 4.0 as well as for 5.0

```
 <repository>
        <id>lucene-repository</id>
        <name>Lucene Maven</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
 </repository>
```

and if you need the latest docs ... [look no further](https://builds.apache.org//job/Lucene-trunk/javadoc/demo/overview-summary.html#overview_description)